# Google Adword script aborting with following error:The return value passed to the callback function must be a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

Need help with google adwords script.

My script is aborting within second of starting.Script does run intermittently.

The error message says:

10/4/2018 10:53:08 AM   Aborted the script
10/4/2018 10:53:09 AM   The return value passed to the callback function must be a string.

Here is the whole script:The script updates the spreadsheet with disapproved keywords from google.

```
    /**
* This report Finds broken URLs

*/


//Standard Global Variables
var details = "";
var fobGroupNum = 0;
var runStage = 0;
var fobGroup = {};
var cur_sheet = "";
var fobGroupName = "";
var ss = "";
var accountIds = [];
var reportDescription = '';

//FOB Global Vars
var fobGroups = [{
  fobList: ['Apparel'],
  sheets: {
    DisapprovedKeywords: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1',
    NoAdGroups: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc2',
    BrokenURLs: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc3',
    DisapprovedAds: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc4',
    History: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc5'
  }
}, {
  fobList: ['Center Core', 'Hispanic'],
  sheets: {
    DisapprovedKeywords: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyz1',
    NoAdGroups: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyz2',
    BrokenURLs: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyz3',
    DisapprovedAds: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyz4',
    History: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyz5'
  }
}, {
  fobList: ['Home'],
  sheets: {
    DisapprovedKeywords: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/def1',
    NoAdGroups: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/def2',
    BrokenURLs: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/def3',
    DisapprovedAds: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/def4',
    History: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/def5'
  }
}, {
  fobList: ['TM/Seasonal'],
  sheets: {
    DisapprovedKeywords: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mno1',
    NoAdGroups: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mno2',
    BrokenURLs: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mno3',
    DisapprovedAds: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mno4',
    History: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/mno5'
  }
}];
var reportDescriptions = {
  DisapprovedKeywords: 'Disapproved Keywords',
  NoAdGroups: 'Ad Groups with No Active Ads',
  BrokenURLs: 'Keywords with Invalid URLs',
  DisapprovedAds: 'Disapproved Ads'
}

/**
* The function that starts the process
*/
function main() { 
  //Initialize Variables
  var canRun = init(true);
  if(!canRun){
    Logger.log("Aborted the script");
    return false;
  }

  //Clear all sheets in spreadsheet
  clearSheets(ss);

  //Get the accounts from accountIds
  var accountSelector = MccApp.accounts().withIds(accountIds);

  // Process the account in parallel.
  accountSelector.executeInParallel('processAccount', 'allFinished', 1);
}

/**
* Post-process the results from processAccount. This method will be called
* once all the accounts have been processed by the executeInParallel method
* call.
*/
function allFinished(results) {
  init();
  var numErrors = 0;
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var n in sheets){
    var rows = sheets[n].getLastRow()-1;
    if(rows>0){
      numErrors+=rows;
    }
  }

  //log if there were issues?
  if(numErrors>0){
    Logger.log("%s had %s %s", fobGroupName, numErrors, reportDescription);
    //Consolidate all data to a single sheet
    consolidateSheets(ss, "All Results");
    //Compile the list of Managers and emails to send report to
    var fobs = getFobs();
    var managers = [];
    var emails = [];

    for( hob in fobGroup.fobList ){
      managers = managers.concat(fobs[fobGroup.fobList[hob]].getManagers());
      emails = emails.concat(fobs[fobGroup.fobList[hob]].getContacts());
    }
    //Normalize the list to make sure there are no repeat emails sent
    var contacts = {};
    for(var n in managers){
      contacts[emails[n]]=managers[n];
    }
    if(debug){
      //overwrite contacts with contacts on the debug list if we're debuggin'
      contacts = {"abc@abc.com":"abc", 
                    "xyz@xyz.com":"xyz" } 
 else {
;
    }

    //Compile the message subject and body
    var subject = (Number(numErrors)-1)+" "+reportDescription+" found in "+fobGroup.fobList.join(' & ')+" Today.";
    var body = "There are "+subject+"\n The detailed report can be accessed at the following URL: \n "+fobGroup.sheets[reportName];

    //Send message to each contact individually (not sure how to do it all at once)
    for(var e in contacts){
      MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, "Hi "+contacts[e].split(" ")[0]+", \n"+body);
      Logger.log("Sending email to %s at %s", contacts[e], e);
    }

  } else {
    Logger.log("%s had no %s", fobGroupName, reportDescription);
  }
  details.setErrors(numErrors);
  details.setStatus("Complete");
  Logger.log("The script is done");
}

//A safe way to select or add a sheet (tab) to a spreadsheet
function getSheetByAccount(ss, accountName){
 try {
   ss.insertSheet(accountName);
   Logger.log("Sheet %s was created", accountName);
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log("Sheet %s exists, Selecting it %s", accountName, e);

 }
  return ss.getSheetByName(accountName);
}

//Add sheet headers to sheet
function addSheetHeaders(sheet){
  // Append header rows based on the selected column from the report including Account Name.
  for(var n in sheetHeaders){
    sheet.getRange(1, Number(n)+1).setValue(sheetHeaders[n]);
  }
  //Set the formatting of the headers
  var heads = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheetHeaders.length);
  heads.setBorder(false, true, true, true, true, null).setFontWeight('bold');
  sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
}

//Consolidate all sheets into one and delete the individual results
function consolidateSheets(ss, sheetName){
  var sName = sheetName || "Default";
  var resSheet = getSheetByAccount(ss, sName);
  resSheet.clear();
  addSheetHeaders(resSheet);
  var resRow = 2;
  var cols = resSheet.getMaxColumns();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var n in sheets){
    //Skip the Results sheet
    if(sheets[n].getName()!=resSheet.getName()){
      //Get number of rows in sheet
      Logger.log("Getting rows for %s Sheet.", sheets[n].getName());
      var rows = 0;
      try {
        rows = sheets[n].getLastRow()-1;
      } catch (e){
        Logger.log("Oops, can't get rows in sheet %s : %s", sheets[n].getName(), e);
      }
      if(rows>0){
        //Get the range to copy start at second row to not copy header
        var fromRange = sheets[n].getRange(2, 1, rows, cols);

        //Copy data to consolidated sheet
        fromRange.copyValuesToRange(resSheet, 1, cols, resRow, rows+resRow);

        //Add better headers to the account's sheet
        try {
          addSheetHeaders(sheets[n]);
        } catch(e){
          Logger.log("Oops, can't set headers for sheet %s : %s", sheets[n].getName(), e);
        }

        //Increment the starting row of consolidated sheet
        resRow+=rows;
      } else {
        //Delete the sheet with no data
        try {
          ss.deleteSheet(sheets[n]);
        } catch(e) {
          Logger.log("Can't delete sheet %s : %s", sheets[n].getName(), e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//Delete all of the sheets except for one (can't delete all of them)
function clearSheets(ss, sName){
  var sheetName = sName || "Default";
  //See if there's a default sheet
  getSheetByAccount(ss, sheetName);
  //Clear all sheets in spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var n in sheets){
    if(sheets[n].getName() == sheetName){
      sheets[n].clear();
    } else {
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[n]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Removed %s sheets from spreadsheet", sheets.length);
}

//Don't change this stuff


function getGroupNum(){
  var details = runDetails();
  return details.getFOB();
}

/* Run Details Manager
* This portion takes care of the FOB group selection 
* so this report can be run multiple times to handle
* all of the FOBs with a single script as a workaround
* for the executeInParallel limitation
*/
function runDetails(){
  this.dateRow = 2;
  this.fobRow = 3;
  this.statusRow = 4;
  this.stageRow = 5;
  this.errorsRow = 5;
  this.reportField = 0;
  this.group = 0;
  this.run_sheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/stu';
  this.run_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(this.run_sheet_url);
  this.run_sheet = this.run_ss.getActiveSheet();
  this.runDate = "";
  this.runFOB = "";
  this.runStatus = "";
  this.runStage = "";
  this.getDetails = function(){
    var runData = this.run_ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    //get the mapping of date field and report field
    for(var n in runData[0]){
      if(runData[0][n]==reportName){
        //Logger.log("We found the report name in %s", n);
        this.reportField = n;
        break;
      }
    }
    //Logger.log("runData = %s", runData);
    var lastDate = runData[dateRow-1][reportField];
    //var lastDate = runData[1][1];
    var numRuns = runData[fobRow-1][reportField];
    this.runDate = lastDate;
    this.runFOB = numRuns;
    this.runStatus = runData[statusRow-1][reportField];
    this.runStage = runData[stageRow-1][reportField];
    return {
      'date':this.runDate,
      'FOB':this.runFOB,
      'status':this.runStatus,
      'stage':this.runStage
    };
  }
  this.getFOB = function(){
    var runData = this.getDetails();
    //Converting report field to sheet-compatible (starts at 1 not 0);
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    var runtimes = 0;

    var today = getDateString();
    if(runData.date == today){
      if(runData.status=="Running"){
        return runData.FOB;
      } else {
        Logger.log("FOB report done for %s, attempting to run it for %s", runData.FOB, Number(runData.FOB)+1);
        this.setStatus("Running");
        //this.setStage(1);
        this.setFOB(Number(runData.FOB)+1);
        return this.runFOB;
      }
    } else {
      //wasn't run today yet
      this.setStatus("Running");
      //this.setStage(1);
      this.setDate(today);
      this.setFOB(0);
      return 0;
    }
  };
  this.setStatus = function(status){
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    this.runStatus = status;
    Logger.log("Attempting to set status to %s in row %s column %s", status, this.statusRow, thiscol);
    this.run_sheet.getRange(this.statusRow, thiscol).setValue(status);
  };
  this.setFOB = function(num){
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    this.runFOB = num;
    this.run_sheet.getRange(this.fobRow, thiscol).setValue(num);
  };
  this.setDate = function(day){
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    this.runDate = day;
    this.run_sheet.getRange(this.dateRow, thiscol).setValue(day);
  };
  this.setStage = function(stage){
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    this.runStage = stage;
    Logger.log("Setting to stage %s", stage);
    this.run_sheet.getRange(this.stageRow, thiscol).setValue(stage);
  };
  this.setErrors = function(errors){
    var thiscol = Number(this.reportField)+1;
    var thisrow = this.errorsRow + this.runFOB;
    this.run_sheet.getRange(thisrow, thiscol).setValue(errors);
  }
  this.getDetails();
  return this;
}

/**
* Initialize the process by getting FOBs, sheets and account IDs
* this function doesn't have much value anymore since accessing the sheet
* variable from the global scope was quite problematic
*/
function init(begin){
  details = runDetails();
  fobGroupNum = details.getFOB();
  fobGroup = fobGroups[fobGroupNum];
  reportDescription = reportDescriptions[reportName];

  //Fails if there's no FOB group so it won't keep running and sending erroneous emails
  if(!fobGroup){
    return false;
  }
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(fobGroup.sheets[reportName]);

  fobGroupName = fobGroup.fobList.join(', ');

  if(begin){
    //do this only for the first run to get account IDs for accountSelector
    var fobs = getFobs();
    // Select the accounts to be processed. You can process up to 50 accounts.
    // Get the account IDs in this fob group
    for( hob in fobGroup.fobList ){
      accountIds = accountIds.concat(fobs[fobGroup.fobList[hob]].getAccountIds());
    }
    Logger.log("Opening %s %s FOB Accounts", accountIds.length, fobGroupName);
  }
  return true;

}

/**
* Get the FOBs
*/
function AccountListMapper(head){
  that = {};
  that.accountName = head.indexOf("Account");
  that.accountId = head.indexOf("Customer ID");
  that.fob = head.indexOf("FOB");
  that.hob = head.indexOf("HOB");
  that.manager = head.indexOf("FOB Manager");
  that.contact = head.indexOf("Contact E-mail");
  return that;
}
function Fob(options, mapper){
  this.name = options[mapper.hob];
  this.accounts = [];
  this.accountIds = [];
  this.managers = options[mapper.manager].replace(", ", ",").split(",");
  this.contacts = options[mapper.contact].replace(", ", ",").split(",");
 // this.mapper = mapper;
  this.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
  };
  this.getManagers = function(){
    return this.managers;
  }
  this.getContacts = function(){
    return this.contacts;
  }
  this.addAccount = function(data){
    //make sure the account fob matches
    if(this.getName() == data[mapper.hob]){
      var account = {
        name: data[mapper.accountName],
        id: data[mapper.accountId],
        fob: data[mapper.fob],
        hob: data[mapper.hob]
      };
      this.accounts.push(account);
      this.accountIds.push(account.id);
      //Logger.log("Adding account %s %s to %s FOB", data[mapper.accountName], data[mapper.accountId], data[mapper.hob]);
      return true;
    } else {
      //Logger.log("%s is not %s", this.getName(), data[mapper.hob]);
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.getAccountIds = function(){
    return this.accountIds;
  }
  this.getAccounts = function(){
    return this.accounts;
  }
  this.getAccount = function(id){
    return this.accounts[this.accountIds.indexOf(id)];
  }
}
/**
 * Left pad numbers to normalize dates
 */ 
function padLeft(nr, n, str){
  if(String(nr).length >= n){
    return nr;
  } else {
     return Array(n-String(nr).length+1).join(str||'0')+nr;
  }
}
/**
 * Normalize Any Date String
 */
var normalizeDateString = function(dateString){
  outDate = "";
  if(dateString.length < 12){
    d = new Date();
    return(dateString + "T" + padLeft(d.getHours(), 2) + ":" +
      padLeft(d.getMinutes(), 2) + ":" + padLeft(d.getSeconds(), 2)+"-"+
      padLeft(d.getTimezoneOffset()/60, 2)+":"+
      padLeft(d.getTimezoneOffset()%60, 2));
  } else {
    return(dateString);
  }
}
function getDateString(){
  return getTodayDateString()+" What!?";
}

function getTodayDateString(){
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + "-" + padLeft(d.getMonth()+1, 2) + "-" + padLeft(d.getDate(), 2);
}


function getFobs(){
 var sheet_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/stu'; 
  //var fob_col = "D";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet_URL);
  //var rows = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows(); //number of rows in sheet
  var fobData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var fobs = new Object();
  var mapper = AccountListMapper(fobData[0]);
  for(i=1; i<fobData.length; i++){
    if(!fobs[fobData[i][mapper.hob]]){
      fobs[fobData[i][mapper.hob]]=new Fob(fobData[i], mapper);
    }
    fobs[fobData[i][mapper.hob]].addAccount(fobData[i]);
    //Logger.log("Added %s to %s FOB", fobData[i][mapper.accountName], fobData[i][mapper.hob]);
  }
  return fobs;
}
```

Comment: Hi @user10354614 and welcome to StackOverflow. Would it be possible for you to create a plunkr or similar, reproducing the issue? You can just edit your question and paste in the URL to plunkr. That will make it easier for the community to provide feedback

Comment: What function is exactly giving you this error? is it `executeInParallel` if so can you give the prototype of the function please?

Comment: @JSmith..Added the whole script

Comment: @user10354614 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You should not post the entirety of a complex script.

Answer (score 1):

The [executeInParallel(functionName, optionalCallbackFunctionName, optionalInput)](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/reference/mccapp/mccapp_managedaccountselector#executeInParallel_3) only accepts the `string` format for the `optionalInput` parameter.

> Optional. A string that can be specified that will be passed into the function being executed for each account.

Your code is providing an integer instead of a string:

```
accountSelector.executeInParallel('processAccount', 'allFinished', 1);
```